# ExtJS 4 ComboBox AutoComplete

Tags: extjs, autocomplete, combobox, extjs4

I have an extjs combobox used for auto-complete having following configuration:

```
xtype:'combo',
displayField: 'name',
valueField:'id',
store: storeVar,
queryMode: 'remote',
minChars:2,
hideTrigger:true,
forceSelection:true,
typeAhead:true
```

There are two issues being faced by me:

a. **If a user chooses a value from the list returned from server, but later wants to remove that value and keep combo-box empty, then also the old values re-appears on blur, not allowing combo-box to remain empty. How can I allow empty value in this combo-box in such a case?** I understand it could be due to forceSelection:true, but then I need to keep it true as otherwise user can type any random value.

b. **When the server returns an empty list, I want to display a message - No Values Found**. I tried doing this, by putting this value in the displayField entity, i.e., {id:'', name:'No Value Found'}. But then in this case, the user is able to choose this value and send it to server which is not what is expected. Thus, how can I display the message for empty list?

Could someone please throw light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the issue related to forceSelection in the question above, following is the hack created which can serve the expected purpose:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.ComboBox,{          
    assertValue: function() {
        var me = this,
            value = me.getRawValue(),
            rec;
        if (me.multiSelect) {
            // For multiselect, check that the current displayed value matches the current
            // selection, if it does not then revert to the most recent selection.
            if (value !== me.getDisplayValue()) {
                me.setValue(me.lastSelection);
            }
        } else {
            // For single-select, match the displayed value to a record and select it,
            // if it does not match a record then revert to the most recent selection.
            rec = me.findRecordByDisplay(value);
            if (rec) {
                me.select(rec);
            } else {
                if(!value){
                    me.setValue('');
                }else{
                    me.setValue(me.lastSelection);
                }
            }
        }
        me.collapse();
    }
});
```

This needs to be included after library files of extjs have been included.

For the other issue of message to be shown at No Values Found - emptyText - works fine as suggested by Varun.

Hope this helps somone looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this for Ext JS 3.3.1. I don't know if they apply to Ext JS 4, though I guess they should.

For the first problem, set `autoSelect : false`. `autoSelect` is by default set to `true`. This will work only if `allowBlank : true` is set. From the docs

> true to select the first result gathered by the data store (defaults
>   to true). A false value would require a manual selection from the
>   dropdown list to set the components value unless the value of
>   (typeAheadDelay) were true.

For the second problem, use `listEmptyText`. From the docs

> The empty text to display in the data view if no items are found.
>   (defaults to '')

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Varun, Thanks for answering. 

autoSelect actually is highlighting the first entry in the list and not serving the purpose of removing the old value and allowing null. And for listEmptyText - I couldn't locate this config in ExtJS4 docs, may be it has been called off.

So I tried both of them but couldn't get them to work in ExtJs 4 unfortunately, and still looking for some solution.

Comment: I just checked the docs, the `listEmptyText` can now be set through the `listConfig`'s `emptyText` option. Try that. I haven't tried it myself. Check `allowBlank` property again.. That is the only config that will cause Issue 1.

Comment: Hey Varun, thanks for the post. I confirm that emptyText under listConfig worked successfully. Thanks again.

As for null value, I feel that forceSelection:true is overriding other options, thus, even if I do allowBlank:true, but there is no Null value present in the values list, then combo-box populates the old value back. One way of addressing this I feel can be of sending an empty record from the server side but unfortunately its not that elegant. 

Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Instead of doing that, just write a `blur` event on the `combo` and clear the `valueField` property whenever the `combo.getRawValue()` is null or empty.

Comment: Thanks Varun, I tried with getRawValue(), but null or empty doesn't appear in it as a value ever. When value in combobox is removed, then also getRawValue() is returning the old value. Thus, on blur, its not getting possible to check what you mentioned. Thanks again for all help so far.

Comment: tat means the blur event is getting fired after the value is set.. then try out `beforeselect` or `change` events too.. if nothing works post a bug in the extjs forums at www.sencha.com. Cheers!